# Test files and features files to be in different directories

Tags: python, bdd, pytest

How to make test files and feature files in different directories in py-test-bdd?

I have had a look at the py-test documentation under "Organizing your scenarios" section.

My current structure is:

```
bdd
  |
  feature directory
                  |
                  feature file #1 (named log.feature)
                  feature file #2
                  feature file #3      
  |
  test file #1
  test file #2
  test file #3
```

with current code doing:

```
@scenario('features/log.feature', 'scenario description #1')
```

But instead what I would actually like is:

```
bdd
  |
  feature directory
                  feature file #1
                  feature file #2
                  feature file #3      
  |
  test directory (named tests)
                test file #1
                test file #2
                test file #3
```

I tried writing the code:

```
@scenario('bdd/features/log.feature', 'scenario description #1')
```

**But when executing this line above what is actually tries to do is bdd/tests/bdd/features/log.feature and obviously it throws an error directory does not exist.

How do I get it to do bdd/features/log.feature ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just need to do ../ to jump to preceding directory. ie:

```
@scenario('../features/log.feature', 'scenario title #1')
```

If you have more directories, just need to do ../../../ and repeat ../ as many times as directories as you want to go upwards.

If you have more than 1 scenario, then just declare a variable at the top and pass in this variable to every @scenario, ie:

```
myFilePath = '../features/log.feature'
@scenario(myFilePath, 'scenario title #1')
@given('blah....')
@then('blah....')

@scenario(myFilePath, 'scenario title #2')
@blah
```